# Error when displaying data according to the id in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a problem that I do not know exactly how to solve it, I have a page that shows some questions asked, taken from the database and I made a comments section, how could I get comments according to post_id? I tried to take them and normal but it is not displayed, I did something like:

Route::

```
Route::get('/viewUserQuestion/{post}', 'PostsController@viewUserQuestion')->name('viewQuestion');
```

Controller:

```
 public function viewUserQuestion(Post $post, Comment $comment) { return view('viewQuestion', compact('post'), compact('comment'));
```

Only if I have something like comment [0] -> commentText will be shown to me, if I do not receive an error, a suggestion how can I take them according to the id?

Schema::

````
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('post_id')->default();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->text('commentText');
        $table->timestamps();
    });```
````

...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you return your view, you are not passing the variables to it correctly

```
return view(
    'viewQuestion', 
     compact('post'), 
     compact('comment')
);
```

This is going to pass a third argument to the `view()` method rather than having both `post` & `comment` as part of a single array. I'd recommend reading the documentation in `compact()` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) for a better understanding of what it does, but in essence it just makes an assocative array.

You would want to do something like this instead:

```
return view('viewQuestion', [ 
     'post' => $post
]);
```

---

If you have a `Post` model with a `hasMany()` relationship to your `Comment` model

**Post Model**

```
/**
 * A Post has many Comments.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'post_id');
}
```

You can access all comments simply by going `$post->comments`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function viewUserQuestion(Post $post) 
{ 
    $comment = Comment::where('post_id',$post->id)->get();
    return view('viewQuestion', compact('post','comment'));
}
```

Or change route to.

```
   Route::get('/viewUserQuestion/{post}/{comment}', 'PostsController@viewUserQuestion')->name('viewQuestion');
```

To use this route, you must also send a comment id

Good Luck